# grails pagination tag don't access method

Tags: grails, pagination

I'm newbie to grails and I've tried to use the grails pagination Tag found here [link text](http://www.grails.org/GSP+Tag+-+paginate)
 
and when i tried to use it like he says like the this 
Controller :

```
 def pageslist = {
 [pages: Page.list(params)]
}
```

view

```
 < g:paginate next="Forward" prev="Back" maxsteps="5" controller="story" action="pageslist" total="${story.pages.count()}" />
```

it gives me nothing at all and the debugger never enter the controller method.. what is the problem and is there any other way for paginating in server side way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<g:paginate next="Forward" prev="Back" maxsteps="5" controller="story" 
            action="pageslist" total="${pages.count()}" />
```

Because you've returned a map `[pages: Page.list(params)]` as the model from your controller, you will be able to access the variable `pages` from your view.

Edit:

You need to get the total count of Pages that you want to paginate through.  Either use `total="${Page.count()}`" or add another variable to your model.

see the [documentation on the Paginate tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/paginate.html) for more.

Comment: i will try it sir and will confirm you asap :) can't tell you how much i appreciate it

Comment: You shouldn't use `pages.count()` for the total attribute, since `pages` is the already paginated list of pages (i.e. only the pages that are displayed in the current pagination step). The `total` attribute, however, expects the *total* number of items (for it to be able to determine the total number of pagination steps).

Comment: it didn't work it said that it can't get count on null object.. it means pages.. and when i make null safe pages?.count() it gives me another error message that 
Tag [paginate] is missing required attribute [total]

that means that the problem persist that the paginate don't call the pageslist function at all :(

Comment: and btw if i give it a static total for testing it just gives me the paging numbers with strange links ... where should the content of the pages come.. and why does the links give me something like this
http://localhost:8080/egypths/story/pageslist?offset=10&max=10
which genereate 404 error of course.. did i miss something?? it seems yes but what?

Comment: Daniel you are right, he needs to add another variable. I just wanted to quickly point out that story.pages.count() doesn't work.

Comment: so what is the solution do you think in my case..
you can access my project through githun
http://github.com/emadhegab/egypths

Answer (score 2):

You should use as Colin sugested last, `${Page.count()}` and import Page into your gsp:

```
<% import pa.ck.age.Page %>
```

or you can  add another param to the model returned to the view:

```
def pageslist = {
   [pages: Page.list(params), total: Page.count()]
}
```